# form_for data not submitting to mysql database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my view page I have a form like

```erb
<%= form_for (@writereview), url:
    createreview_path(@writereview),:class=>"form-horizontal",method: :post do |f|  %>
<div class="form-inline">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="clean">Cleanliness</label>
    <%= f.select(:clean, [['1', 1], ['1.5', 2], ['2',3],['2.5',4],['3',5],['3.5',6],['4',7],['4.5',8],['5',9]],{},{ :class => "form-control"}) %>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="clean">Food</label>
    <%= f.select(:food, [['1', 1], ['1.5', 2], ['2',3],['2.5',4],['3',5],['3.5',6],['4',7],['4.5',8],['5',9]],{},{ :class => "form-control"}) %>
</div>
```

and in controller action -

```rb
def create
    @writereview = WriteReview.new(params[:writereview])
    if @writereview.save!
        redirect_to root_path
    end
end

private

def user_params
    params.require(:writereview).permit(:clean,:food,:locality,:behavior,:amenity,:likes,:dislikes,:comment)
end
```

Comment: but while submitting data is not saving into db in log file  -Started POST "/createreview" for ::1 
Processing by ResultController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"IsBgADlTGK4AUrQfLQUx9lKTXf1HkePhMo/JaOSim979Zm4XCUEtoGF7o9uCrEdm1ilQleMst5N75ZFfryrv1A==", "write_review"=>{"clean"=>"2", "food"=>"3", "locality"=>"2", "behavior"=>"5", "amenity"=>"1", "likes"=>"", "dislikes"=>"", "comment"=>""}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
   INSERT INTO `write_reviews` (`created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2015-12-06 16:04:01', '2015-12-06 16:04:01')
 

Completed 302

Answer (score 0):

Use following code:

```
def create 
   @writereview = WriteReview.new(user_params)
  if @writereview.save!
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using your santization, but that isn't causing your problem.

```
def create 
  @writereview = WriteReview.new(write_params)
end

private
def write_params 
  params.require(:writereview).permit(:clean,:food,:locality,:behavior,:amenity,:likes,:dislikes,:comment)
end
```

I'd look at the model, the database schema.  Your model does not know about clean, food, locality, behavior, amenity, likes, dislikes, etc.  I know this because:

```
 INSERT INTO write_reviews (created_at, updated_at) VALUES ('2015-12-06 16:04:01', '2015-12-06
```

There are no fields that are being recorded to the record, Your schema is not aware of these fields, so nothing is recorded.